# How to create a "master" branch in a Git repo after an initial commit has been made?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I've created a feature branch in an **empty** Git repo and pushed it to Github. Now I can't create a PR from it as it's considered a "default" branch and there's no `master` branch. How can update the repo so that:

- There's a `master` branch (say, pointing to a commit adding an empty `README` file)
- There's a feature branch with my change, which can be used to create a PR ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean you are using tow branches ? then merge your work branch to the master branch on local repo & git push too your github repo after that

Comment: No, I don't have `master` locally, just a feature branch with a single commit, which is the initial commit in the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your question, your repository now looks like this:

```
o
^
feature
```

and you want to make it look like this:

```
o-------o
^       ^
master  feature
```

while also making `master` the new [default branch on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-the-default-branch), instead of `feature`.

One way to go about it is to create a new "initial" commit on the `feature` branch, move it to the beginning of the history and create a new `master` branch that points to it.

Here are the steps:

```
git checkout feature
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit" (you can create the README file here, instead)
git rebase -i --root

# The TODO file will look something like this:

pick 1234abc Adds the feature
pick 5678edg Initial commit

# Move the "Initial commit" line to the top of the file

pick 5678edg Initial commit
pick 1234abc Adds the feature

# Then save and close
```

At this point, your history will look like this:

```
o-------o
        ^
        feature
```

Now, create the `master` branch pointing to the commit *before* the one referenced by `feature`:

```
git checkout -b master feature^
```

At this point, all you have to do is push `master` to GitHub with:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Finally, you'll have to go to your repository's settings on GitHub to make `master` the new default branch. See GitHub's documentation on [how to do that](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-the-default-branch).

Answer (score 0):

If your repository only has a feature branch, and that branch only has a single commit, and the repository in GitHub has no commits, just rename your feature branch to master and push it. No need for a pull request.

Everything has to start somewhere. The first commit to a new repository doesn't need a pull request. A pull request needs two branches so you can view the changes introduced. Since this is a new repository, there are no new changes.

Comment: I get what you're saying but there still might be cases where you find it valuable to have a PR so someone can review your initial code.